# how to store private key securely in application in android?

Tags: android, cryptography

i want to store a private key securely in my application. I read a lot of SO question but failed to find proper answer?

`Sharedpreference` is the way to store securely but rooted phone can easily find it.

Can any one tell me how to store securely a `key = "The real world"` in android app?

Thanks

Comment: See the Key chain section for security related strings. [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html) Google Keychain example in github repo. [Keychain](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/blob/master/KeyChainDemo/src/com/example/android/keychain/KeyChainDemoActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

Symmetric Encryption Example - AES
Here is one very popular and highly efficient symmetric algorithm called -- Advanced Encryption Standard (AES). Based on the Rijndael cipher developed by two Belgian cryptographers, AES has been adopted by the U.S. government and is now used worldwide.

use as:

initialize

```
    private SecretKeySpec secrateKeyInit() {
    SecretKeySpec sks = null;
    try {
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        sr.setSeed("any data used as random seed".getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(128, sr);
        sks = new SecretKeySpec((kg.generateKey()).getEncoded(), "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AES secret key spec error");
    }
    return sks;
}
```

//for incode data

```
private byte[] IncodeData(SecretKeySpec sks, String simplestring) {
    // Encode the original data with AES
    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        encodedBytes = c.doFinal(simplestring.getBytes());//store this any were
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AES encryption error");
    }
    return encodedBytes;
}
```

for decode data:

```
    private String Decrypt(SecretKeySpec sks, byte[] incodeddata) {
    String value = null;
    // Decode the encoded data with AES
    byte[] decodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        decodedBytes = c.doFinal(incodeddata);
        value = new String(decodedBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "AES decryption error");
    }
    return value;
}
```

save this were u want and use

**OR if u have static string use**

use C++ for store your string in app like

```
  extern "C"
    jstring
    Java_com_shrinkcom_trackvees_utils_AppController_getLogin(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

        std::string hello = "hello";
        return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
    }
```

using it by calling `public native String stringnameincfile`
it returns hello word but its not seen when u Decrypt your apk or any rooted phone

Comment: @rshad sheikh thanks for give a answer. in your IncodeDate method , what is the simple string pass as a parameter? if i have to pass my key value then is is available in application as a hard coded and anyone can easily find it.

Comment: in that case firstly print your encrypt key(string) using above encrypt method in  logcat  then copy result and then use result in your app and use above Decrypt method when you want to use your key

Answer (score 0):

You can securely store it in Shared Preference by encrypting it. Then use KeyStore to also secure the key for decrypting.

**There's no way to 100% secure a data on android but you can make it harder for a hacker to get it. (like encryptions).**

KeyStore: https://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/